How to solve Flutter Appwrite authentication error?
when I am trying to implement signup in my flutter app with appwrite backend I am getting the given error -
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'
But account is created in appwrite backend but in my app/code it's going to catch block not in if(result.$id.isNotEmpty) block. Even If I print result value, it's not working. It's taking me to catch block and showing the given error.
Please help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance!
Here you with code:
late bool isAccountCreating = false;

  Future<void> signUp(
      String email, String password, String name, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      isAccountCreating = true;
      notifyListeners();

      var result = await account.create(
        userId: ID.unique(),
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name,
      );

      print('result value $result');

      if (result.$id.isNotEmpty) {
        // context.go(RouterPath.login);
        CustomSnack.successSnack('Account is created successfully', context);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('catch error ${e.toString()}');
      CustomSnack.warningSnack(e.toString(), context);
    } finally {
      isAccountCreating = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }


Can you post the detail of your pubspec and flutter versions please ?

@ColinLazarini
Here you go with my Flutter version - Channel stable, 3.24.5
in pubspec I am using- appwrite: ^13.1.0
